# Placing a canvas exactly inside a table cell

Tags: html, css

When I place "canvas" tag inside a "td" tag, it automatically increases the column width, there is lot of padding. I want my canvas to fit exactly inside a table cell.

This is my CSS!

```
.mainTable{
width:100%;
height: 1000px;
border: 1px solid black;}

td{
border: 1px groove black;
padding: 1px;}

#animationCanvas_1{
background-color: black;}
```

Someone please help me out!

```
<table class="mainTable">

    <tr id="headingTable"> 
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    <tr id="rowFirst">                  <!-- reflecting balls -->
        <td>
            <canvas id="animationCanvas_1">

            </canvas>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="rowSecond">                 <!-- growing circle with changing color -->
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="rowThird">                  <!-- animation with css only -->
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="rowFourth">                 <!-- random rectangle -->
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="rowFifth">                  <!-- rotating objects -->
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: can you provide a `jsfiddle` example?

Comment: @jiff I haven't done any Javascript coding here

Comment: No i just need your `html` and `css` with `canvas` codes.

Comment: @jiff I have included the html code as well as the css code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you must use `table-layout: fixed;` for your `table`

```
.mainTable {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/muukwnss/2/)**

but there is an alternate way to fix it that use `width` for `td`

```
td {
    border: 1px groove black;
    padding: 0;
    width: 33%;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/muukwnss/1/)**

and if you have issue with your `canvas` for responsive case, you should set `width: 100%;` for canvas.